# How do I format my numbers correctly for an addition equation

Tags: python, addition

Ok, so I am trying to make a program that implements the main() function to make a random addition equation when it is called, using numbers up to 3 digits. This is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    
    import random

# Generating random 3 digit number
    num1 = random.randint(1,1000)
    num2 = random.randint(1,1000)

#Displying the three digit numbers
    print(" ",num1)
    print("+",num2)


    answer = num1 + num2
    user_answer = int(input("Enter sum of numbers: "))
    if user_answer == answer:
        print("Correct answer - Good Work!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect... The Correct answer is:", + answer)
main()
```

The thing I am having issues with is the formatting for the generated numbers. Since they are random, you could generate something like 375 + 67, which would make the output like this:

```
  375
+ 67
Enter sum of numbers:
```

The immediate issue here is that it isn't aligned with the right place, so it is difficult to do addition. I want it to be aligned in the correct place like this:

```
  375
+  67
Enter sum of numbers:
```

Is there an argument in the format function that lets me align it correctly using a blank space like ' '?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the overall width of the equation to be dynamic based on the "widest" number:

```py
a, b = random.sample(range(1, 1001), k=2)
ans = a + b

a, b = map(str, (a, b))
w = max(map(len, (a, b)))

print("{}\n+ {}".format(a.rjust(w + 2), b.rjust(w)))
```

In the above snippet, the `w + 2` accounts for the extra space produced by the plus sign and a single whitespace to its right which will always be present on the bottom row: `'+ '`.

Some sample outputs:

```py
  196
+ 301

  7
+ 9

  1000
+  598

  1000
+ 1000

  487
+  76

    7
+ 676
```

If instead you want a fixed width so that all equations are the same width no matter how many digits are in the "widest" number:

```py
a, b = random.sample(range(1, 1001), k=2)
ans = a + b

a, b = map(str, (a, b))
w = 4  # 4 digits in 1000, the max

print("{}\n+ {}".format(a.rjust(w + 2), b.rjust(w)))
```

Output:

```py
   196
+  301

     4
+    8

  1000
+  598

  1000
+ 1000

   478
+   76

     7
+  682
```

Comment: Is there a simpler or easier way to represent this? I'm a beginner and I haven't learned functions like max(), len(), map(), etc. Is there a way to align it on the numbers with just the format function?

Comment: For the first version, no, because the width is based on how many digits are in the numbers. For the second version, the width is fixed and the solution is simpler

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what is random.sample and why do I have to use that instead of random.randint? When I try it with random.randint, it says "TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'", but when I do your random.sample code it works fine. Also,  what is k and why is it included? It doesn't really look like it does anything by giving k a value.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

Comment: You don't *have* to use it :D it's just easier to grab two numbers chosen randomly out of 1-1000, unpacking them directly into two variables, `a` and `b`

Comment: `map()` takes a function and an iterable, and applies that function to that iterable. In this case, `map(str, (...))` takes whatever is in `(...)` and calls the `str()` function. It's just a different way of doing `a, b = str(a), str(b)`

Answer (score 0):

Try right-aligning the outputs using string formatting. The general syntax would be `f"{yourValue:>width}"`.

```
print(f"{num1:>2}")
print(f"+ {num2:>2}")
```

Comment: That specifies spacing, but how do I get it to align for each random number. Here's an example: The spacing for 

   567
                     
+  24             
does not use the same spacing as 
 
     24

+ 678
So it ends up looking different every time. So, while that would work if you were adding, say 3 digit and 2 digit numbers only, that would work, but it doesn't work for random ones. How do I get the spacing to line up for every random number (up to 3 digits).